# Call UIAlertController and await user interaction

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I know, that the UIAlertController works asynchronous. But I´m searching for a "blocking" solution. With blocking I mean, that following code should be executed after the user taps on the button.

My "AlertBox" is very simple and it´s placed into a "global helper" file, because I use a lot of these AlertBoxes:

```
func showAlertBoxWithOK(headline:String, message:String, OkButtonText:String, viewController:UIViewController) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: headline, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: OkButtonText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
    { action -> Void in
        return
    })
    viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
        return
    })
}
```

Within a view, I call it like this:

```
println ("this is before the AlertBox")
showAlertBoxWithOK("Sample", "Hello World.", "OK", self)
println ("this is after the AlertBox")
```

Code comes to line 1 and prints the text.
Next the AlertBox comes up.
But: Now the line 3 gets executed before the user could confirm the alert.

Is there a way, to stop code processing until user confirmed the AlertBox? Like a very simple "MessageBox" in VisualBasic, that blocks UI and code? Or can it be done like `await`in C# ?

My problem is, that a habe a extrem long code with a lot of AlertBoxes to show...

**EDIT**

Let´s say this is my code:

```
var a = 0
a = a + 5
showAlertBox("5 reached" ...)
a = a + 10
a = a + 15
showAlertBox("30 reached" ...)
a = a + 20
a = a + 25
showAlertBox("75 reached" ...)
```

and so on. I don´t want, that the code steps forward, while AlertBox is shown. And because of the calculations (illustrated with the `a = ...` for simplification) it´s hard to divide all the code into chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than have all of the code in the same method, take the code that you want to have performed after user interaction and put it into another method. Then, when the OK button is pressed have that method be called.

For example:

```
func showAlertBoxWithOK(headline:String, message:String, OkButtonText:String, viewController:UIViewController) {

    a += 5

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: headline, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: OkButtonText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        { action -> Void in
            self.showNextAlertBox("headline2", message: "message2", OkButtonText: "OK", viewController: self)
            return
        })
    viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
        return
    })
}

func showNextAlertBox(headline:String, message:String, OkButtonText:String, viewController:UIViewController) {

    a += 10
    a += 15

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: headline, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: OkButtonText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        { action -> Void in
            return
        })
    viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
        return
    })
}
```

Comment: The AlertBox just shows "information" and does not awaits "choices" from the user. So it´s extremely hard, to divide the very long code into chunks.

Comment: Instead of executing that method in the ok action, have it be called in the completion block of presenting the alert controller.

Comment: What causes the subsequent alerts to be shown? What code is presenting them and what is dismissing the previous alert?

Comment: the user itself dismisses the previous alert by tap on OK. The subsequents are only the code position ...

Comment: I added an example to show what the code would look like.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. But this is not the approach I prefer. Can you give me a hint or example, who I could extend my `ShowAlertBox` in a way, that the function accepts code, that should be executed within `Action`of my OK button? Example call:

            showAlertBox(
                "Hello",
                "Hello World",
                "OK",
                self,
                { println("_____USER PRESSED OK") }
            )

Comment: Sorry. Got it on my own. Thanks a lot for your help !